Rasperry Pi Pico PIO output square wave on button press
I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico and want to achieve the following:
On a button press I need to output 2 periods of a 20 MHz square wave.
I've seen this exampe: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PIOASM?tab=readme-ov-file#usage-example
This example shows how to ouptut a continous square wave. How can I

Limit the number of waveform periods to two
Trigger the output by a given event (button press)
Do the PIOs support 20 MHz in general?

Btw, I'm using Circuit Python for my project.
